# equivalent resistance on looking circuit from two different sides

Tags: current, circuit-analysis

I want to understand how to calculate equivalent resistance if same circuit is looked from two different sides,one from right side and then from left side and how to avoid confusions in this type of circuits ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX2lKh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the equivalent circuit from each side, treat each as a separate problem.  Forget about the fact that there may be a solution from the other side.  They are two independent problems.

As to how to avoid confusion, that is obviously opinion-based and not answerable here.  We have no way to know what you are easily confused by.  Personally, I see nothing confusing here.  Both problems are easily solved by computing series and parallel combinations of resistors.

Comment: can you please suggest a solution to the above problem if we look at circuit from two different sides .

Comment: @sat: That's not on topic of this question, since you asked about looking at the circuit from both sides, and avoiding confusion.  However, I did give you a general method to proceed.  Anything more would be doing your homework for you.  Learn how resistances combine when in series and in parallel.  Once you know that, this problem becomes trivial.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

from the side A

A=R3+R4+R5//R1+R2

A=3+4+5//1+2

A=12//3

A=2.4 Ω

from the side B

B=R3+R1+R2//R4+R5

B=3+1+2//4+5

B=6//9

B=3.6 Ω

This is the answer